# CSS and tables: Displaying lines between columns, but not between rows

Tags: css, html-table

How do I make a HTML table have the following format:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|    Header1     |     Header2     |    Header3    |
----------------------------------------------------
|                |                 |               |
|                |                 |               |
|                |                 |               |
```

What do I have to add or change in my CSS file:

```
body
{
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
}

div, p, th, td
{
    font-size: 14px;
}

table
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

th
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

td
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
td
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Also: `th { border-bottom:1px solid black }` to account for that border, or (if using `thead` properly and avoiding any `th` that might be in your `tbody`) `thead th { ... }`.

Comment: @Phrogz - you're right, I was reading the title rather than the body.

Comment: @Phrogz, @Skilldrick: Fortunately, I don't have to worry about the header, since the background-color of the header is equal to the color of the borders.

Comment: @Eduardo - thanks for the accept - you just made me overtake Jeff Atwood in reputation!

Answer (score 1):

Add border-right to your td style and border to your th style

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the borders you want. Use border-right and border-left on your css to acomplish the effect you want on the required cells only.